# Difference between "Why you say" and "Why did you say" in spoken language

Tags: conjunctions

For example

> Why you say I am idiot?
>
> Why **did** you say I am idiot?

Will Sentence 1 be a natural way to speak? Any grammar mistakes in Sentence 1?

Comment: The construction of sentence 1 is often used by learners, but is grammatically incorrect. It needs an [**auxiliary verb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb). Sentence 2 is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane Will a native speaker use Sentence 1 because it's very normal speech?

Comment: No, a native speaker uses sentence 2. If a native speaker hears sentence 1, they immediately know it was said by a learner, or a non-native.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Or facetious imitation thereof. I'm quite prepared to believe ***Why you no listen**?* has been said more often by native speakers than by the stereotypical nns it's associated with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had forgotten about *"I learn eet from a booke."*

Comment: Are sentences like "why you said..." be normal way to use?

Comment: OK, I've already flagged this post as off-topic.

Comment: I think "Is sentence 1 normal to use?" has been answered several times. No, it isn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane How about "why you **said**..."?

Comment: K. Broflovski, no.